# Can smarty template engine be used to create templates on client side?

Tags: javascript, smarty

My web application uses Smarty templating system on server side to generate content. My application would be using a lot of AJAX interaction. Instead of generating the content on Server side and sending html data to client every time, I would like to send just JSON from server and then bind the data with the Smarty template on Client side.

This would be very helpful in a way that template would be cached on the client side and then I can reuse it for every AJAX interaction and since I would then be just sending JSON data (and not the entire HTML) from the server, I can save a lot on the data that is actually being downloaded.

I know that mustache templating engine can do that since it's language-agnostic but is it possible to do that with Smarty?

What I don't want is to do something like this in JS

```
 for (var i in foo) {
    html += '<div class = "myClass">foo[i].bar</div>';
}

Y.one('#myDiv').set('innerHTML', html);
```

Instead what I want is to have this template of div in the template and then just assign the data to that template

Answer (score 2):

There is a port of PHP Smarty to JScript - http://code.google.com/p/jsmart/

It is free and open-source

With it you can use your existing Smarty templates both in PHP and in JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Smarty works in conjunction with PHP. Since PHP is a server side language you cannot get Smarty to cache client side.

Why not just load the initial structure with placeholders and then for every JSON request, just replace the placeholders in your HTML file?

Comment: Shouldn't your JS layer be handling that stuff anyway?

Comment: The problem with using a placeholder is that it's only good for simple data like variables. But if I have logic also involved there, e.g. a loop, a conditional section etc, the placeholders won't do well. I will then be writing my template again in JS for above scenarios which would defeat the MVC purpose of separating View from other parts

Answer (score 0):

I dont think smarty can as it's PHP specific.  but try this http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/ it's a Microsoft contribution to the jquery project